# Two transaction accessing the same table concurrently from Linked Server in SQL

Tags: sql-server, locking, blocking, linked-server, internals

Table Schema on Linked server

```
Table_Test(id varchar(100) PRIMARY KEY,
           Name varchar(100),
           other columns....)
```

Multiple processes are trying to delete the entries from table based on different ids using below commands called inside SQL Procedure.

```
SET @sql = 'delete from Linked.<DB Name>.dbo.Table_Test where id ='''+ @id+''''
Exec(@sql)
```

It is working fine with non - concurrent request but giving deadlock in concurrent request.

Shouldn't it take row level lock and delete as rows are generally less than 5000 for each id.

or It will behave different for Linked server (Both the servers are SQL Server)

Or where i can get documentation/resources for deep diving into Linked servers locking issue.

Comment: I have tried using `SET @sql = 'delete from <DB Name>.dbo.Table_Test where id ='+ @id Exec(@sql ) AT LINKED`

Comment: Firstly, you should parameterize the query properly,  by passing in `@id` as a parameter, and using `QUOTENAME` for the DB. Then please share a query plan on both local and remote servers of the parallel version via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: @Charlieface this code snipped is a sample not a exact code, we are passing parameter properly quoted.  And this query is being called inside SQL Proc.

Comment: To diagnose a deadlock, we need the *real* queries being run, including any queries in the same transaction, the *actual* not *estimated* query plans, and table and index definitions. Can't help without information

Comment: @Charlieface - Let me get back to you with these details too. It could take sometime. Meanwhile if you could point out few resources regarding Linked server, deadlock and blocking in SQL Server. It would also help me. Thanks

Comment: Obviously we need the deadlock XML graph also. See https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5100/lesson-on-sql-server-deadlocks-and-how-to-solve/ and https://www.quest.com/community/blogs/b/database-management/posts/avoiding-sql-deadlocks-with-query-tuning-advice-from-brent-ozar and https://www.brentozar.com/sql/deadlocks/